# PasswordAuthentication cannot be resolved to type Error

Tags: java, authentication

I am creating a class extending java.net.Authenticator to authenticate my FTP Proxy. I am getting errors when I use PasswordAuthentication...

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String user, password;
    public ProxyAuthenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }
    //error here
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

I know people have used these exact lines of code before with no errors. Any idea what's wrong?

EDIT: After importing java.net.PasswordAuthentication, I'm getting an error saying that

java.net.Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication

"overrides java.net.Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication"

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the import for the `PasswordAuthentication` class!!

you either use a fully referenced path like `a.b.c.s.y.PasswordAuthentication` instead of just `PasswordAuthenticator` or you include that class using an import like you did with your `Authenticator` class.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting an error saying ... "overrides java.net.Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication"

Comment: That's what it's saying in Eclipse at least.

Comment: and it is saying that where exactly?

Comment: protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

Comment: looks like getPasswordAuthentication is public in Authenticator class. make it public and it should work

Comment: Still getting the same error. Editted original code to reflect changes. According to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html 




"Subclasses should override the default implementation, which returns null."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26567/discussion-between-user1913362-and-itroubs)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
```

> import the passworkAuthentication class. It will work.